# Duplicates in Map

Tags: apex, force.com

Is it possible to create a Map with duplicate Key

```
Key          Value
Product 1    100
product 1    200
product 2    200
product 2    300
```

Scenario : I have a trigger on quote and have to find the listprice of quotelineitems which have the same product name

I constructed a map with (productname,quotelineitem.listprice)

I have custom setting to check if the map has the key "product name" and then add up all the values

The problem is that I cannot form the above map because I am forgetting the fact that maps cannot have duplicate KEYS :(

IS there a better way to approach this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Map of lists maybe?

```
List<Account> fakeQuotes = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name = 'Prod 1', AnnualRevenue = 100),
    new Account(Name = 'Prod 2', AnnualRevenue = 200),
    new Account(Name = 'Prod 1', AnnualRevenue = 300),
    new Account(Name = 'Prod 2', AnnualRevenue = 400),
    new Account(Name = 'Prod 1', AnnualRevenue = 500)
};

Map<String, List<Double>> listPrices = new Map<String, List<Double>>();
for(Account a : fakeQuotes){
    List<Double> temp = listPrices.get(a.Name);
    if(temp == null) {
        listPrices.put(a.Name, new List<Double>{a.AnnualRevenue});
    } else {
        temp.add(a.AnnualRevenue);
    }
}

System.debug(listPrices); // {Prod 1=(100.0, 300.0, 500.0), Prod 2=(200.0, 400.0)}
```

Comment: The above case worked for me :) !!! Thanks @eyescream

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't it just be easier to create a Map with a List. Something along the lines of:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>>
```

If you are looping over the products:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> prodMap = new Map<String, List<Integer>>();
for(sObject prod:products){
    if(prodMap.get(prod.Name) != null){
        prodMap.get(prod.Name).add(prod.value);
    }else{
        List<Integer> listOfValues = new List<Integer>();
        listOfValues.add(prod.value);
        prodMap.put(prod.Name, listOfValues);
    }
}
```

To add them up you would just then use

```
List<Integer> values = prodMap.get('name');
Integer finalValue = 0;
for(Integer val:values){
    finalValue += val;
}
```

finalValue should then equal the sum of all the values of the product named 'name'.

Answer (score 3):

Use a map of maps! And iterate over the keys like so:

```
Map<Key,Map<Value-Key,Value>
```

How to iterate over this map:

```
Integer i = 0;
List<sObject> products = new List<sObject>(); // assuming this is an sObject of some kind???
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> productValuesByProduct = new Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>();

// build up the map of maps
for(sObject product: products){
    Map<String,Integer> valueEntry = new Map<String,Integer>();
    valueEntry.put('Value',product.get('value'));   
    productValuesByProduct.put(product.get('Name')+String.valueOf(i)),valueEntry);
    i++; // placeholder to avoid key collision
}
```

Again without knowing a lot about your data structures kind of hard to tell... but you can reverse where you put the iterator (i) on either key to loop over inserting multiple values

Comment: Will give this a try never thought on this line !!!

Comment: Can you post an example script for the above map I am trying to understand but saturated and not able to think more :(

Comment: Or probably use map<prod name, list<price>>. Use the map.Keyset.containskey method to see if you have prod name already present, if yes add the price to the corresponding list